# DosBox - no files in directory

Tags: emulation

Why does DosBox not see any files in the directory, please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not clear that you are looking in the correct directory on the Windows side of things.

Comment: `DOCUME~1` is a (horrible) Windows feature that  links DOS-type filenames (the `8.3` format) to "proper" filenames (longer and with less restrictive names). I suspect DOS (which version ?) does not know how to resolve those links. See `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename`.

Comment: I am in the right directory, I added another file, and it was registered by DosBox. I change to C:\ and there are not folders with proper names. I do not know where is the directory C:\.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Windows isn’t involved here, neither is DOS; this is DOSBox, which is using short names following the same pattern as Windows.

Comment: DosBox as other MS-DOS applications may be finicky in terms of supporting long filenames, so you could simply create a folder with at most 8 chars and run your app from it.

Comment: But I do not know where I should create a folder. When I create it, DosBox does not see it. I wrote mount c /home/linux and C:; thus, I should be in the folder /home/linux, right? However, /home/linux/spel gives 'unable to change to'

Comment: Please run `mount` in the DosBox prompt and show the output.

Comment: `rescan` might help too...